# wordpress add_option is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wrote a plugin for wordpress and now I want to add more features into it. One of the feature requires options. To store the options I'm trying to use wordpress functions `add_option`, `update_option` and `get_option`. But when I try to add new option the `add_option` function always returns `FALSE`. I tried `get_option`. This function returns `FALSE` as well. Also I checked the table `wp_options` in the database. There's no this option. Also I have tried to use `update_option` and still get the same result. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post a code snippet so we can 'see' what's going on in your code.

Comment: Update option should be the one you need. Double check that the second parameter you are passing to update option has the value you expect (for instance with `die($youroptionvalue);`. Then do the same with get option immediately after update option to ensure it is set. Otherwise you can't be sure that there isn't some code elsewhere that is updating or deleting that option. You might also consider wp_cache_delete ( 'alloptions', 'options' ); in case you have a caching issue / conflict.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with register_setting().
With this functions u could had an option page to your plugin where the user can change some option.

If you don't know how to use it then check my tutorial [here](http://nozifel.fr/tutoriels/ajouter-des-champs-doptions/)

It's about option for theme, but it works for plugin to :)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting

I hope that help u